# visual studio 2012 slow UI in Parallels

Tags: visual-studio-2012, parallels

**I am running Windows 8 as a virtual machine in Parallels 8 on MAC Pro 2.4Gz Quad with 16 Gig RAM**

I have just upgraded to VS 2012 and I find everything working well except when loading resource files or project setting files.

The UI is incredibly slow at rendering each line to the screen; a resource file with 1000 lines takes about 20 seconds to display!

Worst of all , when you flip to source code and then back to the **open** resource file , it has to render each line all over again!!

I flip back and forth between resource files and source code and it is painfully slow and impossible to develop anything!

I have tried turning off VS visual effects/hardware acceleration etc to no avail.

Is anybody else having these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to speed up rendering by switching the VM to use directX 9 instead of version 10.

If you are having the same problems, in your virtual machine **Config** select **Video** and change:

3D acceleration: **Version 9**

Comment: This worked for me to some degree.  The UI is still sluggish a bit (no where near as bad as the OP).  But now, when I over over menu items, the active item only trails the cursor by about 1/2 as much as before (1-2 items, not 3-5.)  I am on a 2010 macbook pro, i7, 10.9.1 in Parallels 8, 8gb (4 gb for VM), 256mb video ram, 2 CPUs of 4 allocated.